# How to get index of new object on .childMoved

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using an ordered query of the Firebase real-time database. I have a .childMoved listener on the query and when someone's index in the ordered list changes my listener gets fired. However there doesn't seem to be a way to know what the new index of the object is.

```
rtdb.child(refString).queryOrdered(byChild: "queuePosition")
     .observe(.childMoved, with: { snapshot in
         // Do something here with snapshot data
    }) { error in
        // error
    }
```

How can I find out where the object should be moved to? Or should I just do sorting on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Database doesn't expose indexes, since those don't scale well in a multi-user environment. It does have an option to pass the key of the previous sibling of the node with [`observe: andPreviousSiblingKey`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#observe_andprevioussiblingkeywithwithcancel).

With this key you can look up the sibling node, and move the child node after that.